# wcf rest service idempotent

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I am developing a wcf Service in c# and I am searching for a way to make my Service methods or the Service itself as idempotent.
Is there an easy way to do this by marking the Service with an attribute or something like that?
If not does anybody have a code snippet for this?

Answer (score 2):

There's no magic attribute that will make your service idempotent. It's up to your implementation to handle that. For example if your service performs an add to a database then you need to check for the object's existence prior to adding it so you don't add it twice to the db.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is not for a database access, I only want to double posts, I mean when e.g. a page is refreshed the last post is sent twice, but the service should recognize this. Something like accessing the http header ID in a service method and so disallow the command.

Comment: I was just using db access as an example. Whatever you're doing, it's up to your code to make the decision what to do with the request. WCF has no built in mechanism for this.